# Windows 10 - move ALL sub-folders and their contents up one level

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, batch-file, file-management, ms-dos

I have the following:

```
w:\encoded\mp4\movie-1
                      \title00.mp4
                      \title01.mp4 
                      \title02.mp4
              \movie-2
                      \title00.mp4
                      \title01.mp4
                      \title02.mp4
                      \title03.mp4
              \movie-7
                      \title00.mp4
                      \title01.mp4
                      \cover.jpg
              \movie-21
                      \title00.mp4
                      \title01.mp4
```

etc.  I want to basically MOVE all the sub-folders and any files/folders in them UP one level or even to another folder entirely.

So it looks like this:

```
w:\encoded\movie-1
                  \title00.mp4
                  \title01.mp4 
                  \title02.mp4
          \movie-2
                  \title00.mp4
                  \title01.mp4
                  \title02.mp4
                  \title03.mp4
          \movie-7
                  \title00.mp4
                  \title01.mp4
                  \cover.jpg
          \movie-21
                  \title00.mp4
                  \title01.mp4
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows Explorer > Select Subdirs > Cut > Click in destination dir > Paste

Comment: In a batch file `for /d %%A in (W:\encoded\mp4\*) do move "%%A" "%%~dpA.."`

Answer (score 0):

[LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings) is correct in that a For loop of folders can accomplish this. Since you asked to move them up one folder or potentially to a different folder entirely, I've fleshed it out a little bit with some variables to make it easier to change:

```
@echo off

set "src=W:\encoded\mp4"
set "des=W:\encoded"

for /d %%A in (%src%\*) do (
    move "%%A" "%des%"
)
```

It's essentially the same For loop, but you have a variable for your source (`src`) directory and your destination (`des`) directory in case you want to change them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `robocopy`

The `/E` flag includes empty directories, if you don't want to include them, use the `/S` flag.

```
robocopy <source> <destination> /E /MOVE
```

```
robocopy w:\encoded\mp4\ w:\encoded\ /E /MOVE
```